# Как добавить поля пользователю WordPress в кастомную форму?

Tags: wordpress

Есть Интернет магазин на WP, в Личном кабинете я создал вкладку "Компании"  и там  я создал кастомную форму регистрации компании с полями (ИНН, Название компании, КПП) после мне нужно сохранить эти данные пользователю и вывести на странице в виде карточки, добавлю все через add_user_meta, но проблема в том что у меня компаний может быть много, подскажите каким образом мне сохранить данные для авторизованного пользователя неограниченно и выводить карточки компаний?

Comment: Непонятно вообще в чем проблема.

Comment: ACF поля. Очень удобный плагин для wp думаю он вам поможет

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо,в общем решил данную проблему! Что я сделал:

1. Создал свою таблицу в БД wordpress
2. на сайте wp-kama, все действия с бд wordpress очень хорошо описаны,запись, обновления, удаление и прочие. Вот [ссылка](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb)
   Поэтому советую все прочитать и все поймете сразу как я!